# amphtml show amp-img in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, amp-html

I want to load `<amp-img>` on bootstrap modal here is my code:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="exclusive-box">
      <div class="exclusive-inner">
      <a href="">&times;</a></div>
  </div>
  </span>
  </button>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-logo"><a href="">
      <amp-img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" width="600" height="400" layout=responsive ></amp-img>
      </a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

But image is not displaying, same issue is persist when I try to implement it on bootstrap carousel or any other images which display on jQuery event

Answer (score 3):

Can't have any user authored JavaScript code in AMP, only the JavaScript that is provided by the Google AMP team may exist on AMP pages as per [AMP's specifications](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not supported in AMP.

> "AMP is currently focused only on the websites of publications (e.g. newspapers, where the pages are relatively simple and not richly interactive), whereas Bootstrap is aimed at more general usage, including for sophisticated web apps."
>
> - Can't use any custom JS (so any of the Bootstrap components and JavaScript plugins are out); the only way around this would be to define anything that needs JS behavior as an extended component, loaded via  syntax
> - You can only use a subset of HTML and specific tags like  - as Bootstrap itself doesn't actually build the overall page/markup and it's left up to authors, there's not much Bootstrap would need to do here
> - You can only add custom styles as an inline  - this is something that once again an author could/should be doing, not really something that Bootstrap should deal with

-from an "[AMP'd HTML](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17806)"